# convert shape file to raster in matlab

Tags: matlab, point, raster, data-conversion

I would like to convert a shape file to raster grid using matlab. First I tried to do it in Python but I have faced some difficulties and my superior recommended me to use MATLAB. I use matlab randomly and I am pro in it.

The data I have is an ASCII file with a set of points with their coordinates and I want to create a raster grid from them.

I was thinking i can read the data, create an empty matrix with the size of (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax) from data. Then I should assign the z value to each grid cell based on the coordinate of the corresponding point.

The grid size should be 0.5m . I have copied a part of data for your consideration. I would be thankful if somebody help me to find the right way of thinking for this application.

```
32511632.00 5402000.00 354.29 17.50
32511632.50 5402000.00 354.29 17.50
32511633.00 5402000.00 354.35 18.00
32511633.50 5402000.00 354.52 15.75
32511634.00 5402000.00 354.70 12.37
32511634.50 5402000.00 354.61 10.62
32511635.00 5402000.00 354.11 8.50
32511635.50 5402000.00 353.43 9.50
32511636.00 5402000.00 352.72 14.25
32511636.50 5402000.00 352.22 17.62
```

(the first column is X, the second is Y, the third is Z and the last in an attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isize = floor((ymax - ymin) / 0.5) + 1;
jsize = floor((xmax - xmin) / 0.5) + 1
M=zeros(isize, jsize);
```

Then for each input line:

```
i = floor((y - ymin) / 0.5) + 1;
j = floor((x - xmin) / 0.5) + 1;
M(i, j) = z;
```

Comment: I think there is problem with the size of M amtrix. beacuse the file has about 569188 columns, which means the same number for X,Y ans Z value though the M size is (1620,742)

Comment: Try reading this: http://www.mathworks.com.au/support/solutions/en/data/1-FA7L9M/index.html?solution=1-FA7L9M

Comment: Dear user2151446 : Thank you very much for your guidance. The problem is solved now by using linearindexing :)